# calling matrices in a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have some arrays (e.g. 10) of characters in matlab like below:

```
m1=['a1','b1','c1';'a2','b2','c2';'a3','b4','c5']

m2=['aa1','ab1';'aa2','ab2';'aa3','ab4']

...
```

I want to do some analysis on members of each matrix in a loop.
For having access to the members of matrices, I tried this:

```
for i=1:10

my_mat=strcat('m',num2str(i));

%the analysis part

end
```

But this `my_mat` is not equivalent to my m1, m2,... and I got error.

Do you know how can I solve this problem and call my matrices in a loop and have access to their members?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `my_mat=strcat('m',num2str(i));` you are assigning the **name** of your `m1` matrix to `my_mat`, i.e. `my_mat = 'm1'`.

The best practice is to put your matrices in a cell array and loop on the cells:

```
M{1} = m1;
M{2} = m2;
...
```

However, if you insist on looping on variables straight from the workspace you can use `eval` to get the **value** of the variable:

```
my_mat=eval(strcat('m',num2str(1)));
```

Answer (score -1):

As `strcat` just concatenates the strings, the, you should use `eval` to evaluate the string in your code like the following:

```
 eval(strcat('my_mat =',strcat('m',num2str(i))));
```

So, your complete case of your code would be:

```
for i=1:10
    eval(strcat('my_mat =',strcat('m',num2str(i))));
    %the analysis part
end
```

Comment: Note that any answer that goes *"you should use eval"* will very likely get downvoted. It is a bad function to use, even Mathworks dis-encourage its use. Generally speaking: if you need eval, you defined your problem orng

Comment: Could you solve the problem without `eval`?! Also, the above solution used to `eval` too!

Comment: "Generally speaking: if you need eval, you defined your problem wrong". I can tell you how to tie horses to your car so it moves, but if we got to that point is because we are doing something wrong, the car has to move using a different method! Sometimes eval is the only solution. Those times, the problem is worngly posed/understood.